# CSS style elements within <th> scope

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

In HTML, a table header cell (`<th>`) can be given a `scope` attribute to identify whether it is associated with the ensuing column or row or group of them. Is it possible to use a CSS selector to style all table cells (`<td>`) that are associated with the header cell? I.E., style the entire row if `scope="row"` or column if `scope="column"`?

Presupposing the answer is probably "no": then what purpose does the `scope` attribute serve (other than the CSS `[attribute=value]` selector)? Does the browser use it for accessibility options? Or should I ignore it as a developer?

Comment: are you trying to give style to entire row or column or headers ???

Comment: The entire row or column. I believe BoltClock's answer addresses the question well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a CSS selector to style all table cells (`<td>`) that are associated with the header cell? I.E., style the entire row if `scope="row"` or column if `scope="column"`?

Neither Selectors 3 nor Selectors 4 provides a feature for matching a table cell associated with a specific table header cell. The closest is the column combinator, which is as yet unimplemented, only works with column-based headers in HTML tables, and does not carry any header-cell semantics. In particular, the `scope` attribute has no effect on the behavior of the column combinator, and it does not distinguish between a `<th>` and a `<td>`.

Perhaps such a feature might be worth proposing for Selectors 5 (where the column combinator and the `:*-column()` pseudo-classes will most likely end up anyway).

> Presupposing the answer is probably "no": then what purpose does the `scope` attribute serve (other than the CSS `[attribute=value]` selector)? Does the browser use it for accessibility options? Or should I ignore it as a developer?

Some user agents might utilize the `scope` attribute to construct a more meaningful representation of a table. The [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#processing-model-1) describes a table model which may or may not be used by current implementations. The `scope` attribute participates in this table model.

If all of this is Greek to you as an author, then it basically comes down to how much metadata you want in your markup. The more, the better.

Comment: I usually look down on any "dead code" unless it substantially aids readability. But maybe I should be more permissive with HTML attributes, since they can serve in the place of comments, which aren't allowed within an HTML tag.

Answer (score 5):

```
.tableClass th[scope=col] {
    styleme: beautiful;
}
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I see this works, but can anyone find it in MDN or another doc?